# Make a \NewEnviron which holds an lstlisting within a frame of beamer

Tags: beamer, listings, environments

I am setting up a template for a presentation on some sort of code. Thus I would like to have an environment that holds a frame (done with `\usepackage{environ}`) within which I have a lstlisting environment.

The minimal working example, not defined as a new environment would be the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
for i=1:2:10
    do something
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now what I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
\NewEnviron{TFListing}[1][]{
  \begin{frame}[fragile]{#1}
     \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
            \begin{lstlisting}
               \BODY
            \end{lstlisting}
         \end{minipage}
      \end{center}
   \end{frame}
}
```

Which I could then use as:

```
\begin{TFListing}[Title]
    for i=1:2:10
       do something
    end
\end{TFListing}
```

However, the main problem is that latex does not allow reading the `\BODY` argument signalizing the content of the newly defined environment, since it is escaped by the `\begin{lstlisting}`. The benefit of such an environment would be that about eight lines of code per frame could be spared.

Thanks for all of your help in advance.

Comment: This is hard, but, isn't this already a build in feature of the tcolorbox package, amongst all the other things that package can do?

Comment: With `\NewEnviron` you lose line breaks, for instance; but the most important aspect is that the contents is absorbed as the argument to a command, so `listings` can no longer do its job.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few problems with your approach:

1. With `\NewEnviron`, line breaks are lost.
2. The contents of such an environment is absorbed as the argument to a command and `lstlisting` can *never* appear in the argument to a command.
3. Hiding `frame` is bad programming anyway.

Here's a different implementation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{tflisting}[1][]
 {%
  \lstset{
    linewidth=0.9\textwidth,
    xleftmargin=0.05\textwidth,
    #1
  }%
 }{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tflisting}
for i=1:2:10
    do something
end
\end{tflisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use

```
\begin{tflisting}[<listings options>]
```

Comment: How do you mean "Hiding the frame"? Do you mean hiding it in a \NewEnviron command?

Comment: @GianAndreaMüller Masking `frame` inside another environment: I don't think you need it.

Comment: I see your point. I guess it's a question of taste :)
Thanks a lot for your help! I could use your fix really well!

Comment: @GianAndreaMüller I don't see why obfuscating the code just for saving a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand it, this is not easily possible. But at least it can partly be achieved with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{TFListing}[1][]{
 \lstset{caption={#1}}%
 \centering\minipage{.9\textwidth}%
}{
 \endminipage%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{TFListing}[Title]
for i=1:2:10
    do something
end
\end{TFListing}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `center` environment adds some spacing, but the `\centering` macro does not. So, maybe you have to add some vertical spacing manually.